# Driving two Ultrasonic sensor with Arduino

Tags: arduino

everyone.
I've got a problem while I try to use Arduino uno to drive two HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor.
While a try to display two measured value from each sensor, one of them work fine but the other displays value 0.

### My code is shown below:

```
int trigPin=12; // this pin work as the output of the two trig pin of the two sensor
int echoPin1=8;
int echoPin2=13;

 void setup()
 {
   Serial.begin (9600);
   pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(echoPin1, INPUT);
   pinMode(echoPin2, INPUT);
 }
 void loop()
{
   float duration1, distance1, duration2, distance2;

  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); //trig:10 microsecond TTL pulse

  duration1 = pulseIn(echoPin1, HIGH);
  duration2 = pulseIn(echoPin2, HIGH);

  distance1 = duration1/2/29.1;
  distance2 = duration2/2/29.1;
  Serial.print(distance1);
  Serial.print(',');
  Serial.println(distance2);
  delay(20);
```

### }

The situation is that on the Serial Monitor, "distance1" shows correct value however "distance2" is always 0.

I've found that while "duration1" and "duration2" exchange their order(which means duration2 runs first, then duration1 runs.), the result becomes that distance1 shows 0 but distance2 shows correct value.

It seems there are some problems while I using the function "pulseIn", is that right?

Could anyone help me fix this problem, thanks!

Comment: Two sensors works in parallel, but pulseIn functions are executed in serial. This is the reason why your code doesn't work.  Let's image when you toss two balls by your right hand, and try catch them one by one with your right hand. When you catch one ball and put it in a box, another ball had been fallen on the ground.  This is why first pulseIn can get correct value and second one fail to get correct value.  To solve your problem, use two sensors in series, i.e. trigger first sensor then pulseIn for first sensor to get first measurement, and repeat for second sensor.

Comment: Too bad the answer is in a comment.  Now the question cannot be marked answered.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the asynchronous problem, there might be an issue where the sensors interfere with each other by the Ping from one sensor reaching both.

To combat this, you need to ping **one** sensor by pulling it high, and read the length. Then, you'll want a short delay between them to allow the ping to die off. Then, you should do the same for the second sensor.

This allows you to get the most accurate readings.

Answer (score 1):

There are other issues that were raised:

1. Each sensor has its trigger pin, you should send the signal at the trigger pin and read the echo pin form the same sensor, and then repeat for the other sensor.
2. You must perform a reading time, at least 60 ms between readings according to datasheet ([HC-SR04 Datasheet](http://www.micropik.com/PDF/HCSR04.pdf)).
3. Use the interrupt makes the timing most accurate measure.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
int TriggerPIN1 = 9;
int EchoPIN = 10;
int TiggerPIN2 = 5;
int EchoPIN2 = 4;

void setup(){
  pinMode(TriggerPIN1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(EchoPIN2,INPUT);
  pinMode(TriggerPIN2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(EchoPIN2,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  }

void loop(){  
  digitalWrite(TriggerPIN1,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(TriggerPIN1,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(TriggerPIN1,LOW);

  long timedelay = pulseIn(EchoPIN1,HIGH);
  int distance1 = 0.0343 * (timedelay/2);

  Serial.print("Sensor 1 : ");
  Serial.println(distance1);

  delayMicroseconds(2);

  digitalWrite(TriggerPIN2,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(TriggerPIN2,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(TriggerPIN2,LOW);

  long td = pulseIn(EchoPIN2,HIGH);
  int distance2 = 0.0343 * (td/2);

  Serial.print("Sensor 2 : ");
  Serial.println(distance2);
  }
```